# How to remove development code with Webpack?

Tags: webpack, create-react-app

In multiple places I've read Webpack 4+ automatically removes the following from production code:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    // assert something
  }
```

However, the above is still present in the production code. I'm using CRA.

How do I make Webpack remove development code, preferably without unofficial loaders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack does indeed remove such code automatically.

I've mistakenly inspected a source map file, where the development code was obviously present). It's not present in the actual `.js` output.